# different kind of provider configurations in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-providers

Learning angular from different resources on internet makes really confusing. everyone using different kind of patterns to write functions .Kindly throw some light on this [.provider concept](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)

I have tried `.provider` with 4 different pattern and all are working

**pattern A** : using all function inside `return`

```
app.provider('other', function() {
    name ="Default";
    return {
        $get: function () {
                return {
                    sayHello: function () { console.log('provider example say my name is :' + name )}
                }
        },
        setName: function (newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    };
});
```

---

**pattern B :** using `this` and  differ the $get and other methods

```
app.provider('other', function() {
    this.name ="Default";
    this.$get = function () {
        var name = this.name;
        return {
            sayHello: function () { console.log('provider example say my name is :' + name )}
        };
    };

    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});
```

**pattern C :** also found somewhere  using array `[ ]` just before the function which has return

```
this.$get = [function () {
        var name = this.name;
        return {
            sayHello: function () { console.log('provider example say my name is :' + name )}
        }
    }];
```

---

#### UPADTE

**Pattern D:** with .factory and then *functionNameProvider.$get.methodName()* with .config

```
app.factory('alpha', function(){
        var c = ['Cadbury','Perk','Dairy Milk'];
        return {
            sayHello: function() { console.log('Hello, I am from Provider');},
            getAllData: function() { return c; }
        };
});
```

then

```
app.config(['alphaProvider',function(alphaProvider) {
 console.group('Checking Factory Pattern');
 alphaProvider.$get().sayHello();
 var cdata = alphaProvider.$get().getAllData();
 console.log(cdata);
 console.groupEnd();
}]);
```

created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/auy79e87/2/) for the same, Kindly tell me which is correct/preferred way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both patterns A and B are correct ways of creating the provider/service.

The `function` you pass to the `provider()` method is a constructor of the provider instance. Provider instance is simply an object with `$get` method. You have two options on how to instantiate it:

- return the provider instance explicitly from the constructor function (*pattern A*)
- use `this` syntax and return nothing from constructor (*pattern B*). In this case angular will create a provider instance as a new `Object` and run your constructor against it (with `this` bound to it).

The *pattern C* is the [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) - a way to specify the dependencies of your component/function. The array should contain the names of dependencies followed by the `function` where you want them injected. Can be used with both A and B approaches.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by *@estus*, the B approach is more efficient because in case of A  the new `Object` is also created but never used.

Comment: This is not true: 'In this case angular will create a provider instance as a new Object'. In both A and B, `this` instance was already created, it is advisable to use it instead of throwing it to garbage collector. For this reason B is more 'correct' than A.

Comment: I see the other pattern and updated the question. Please guide me